# Suitable 'Union' member type not correctly recognized when parsing XML

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, pyxb

I have been provided with an XSD with the following definition of the type `AnySimple` (I do not know why this type has been defined, but in any case it is distinct from `xsd:anySimpleType`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:Core="http://www.foo.com/Core/PrimitiveTypes" targetNamespace="http://www.foo.com/Core/PrimitiveTypes" elementFormDefault="unqualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">

        <xsd:simpleType name="AnySimple">
            <xsd:annotation>
                <xsd:documentation>container for any simple type</xsd:documentation>
            </xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:union memberTypes="xsd:string xsd:boolean xsd:byte xsd:short xsd:int xsd:long xsd:unsignedByte xsd:unsignedShort xsd:unsignedInt xsd:unsignedLong xsd:float xsd:double xsd:dateTime xsd:duration"/>
        </xsd:simpleType>
        ...
```

After generating Python code from this XSD with pyxb, when I parse an XML document which I know to be valid, **I get the following error which states that an `xsd:int` cannot be an `AnySimple`**:

```
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pyxb/namespace/builtin.py", line 133, in _InterpretTypeAttribute
    raise pyxb.BadDocumentError('%s value %s is not subclass of element type %s' % (type_name, type_en, type_class._ExpandedName))
pyxb.exceptions_.BadDocumentError: xsd:int value {http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}int is not subclass of element type {http://www.foo.com/Core/PrimitiveTypes}AnySimple
```

What has gone wrong?

---

**Edit:**

For reference, here is the generated code for the `AnySimple` type, where the list of members seems to be correct:

```py
# Union simple type: {http://www.foo.com/Core/PrimitiveTypes}AnySimple
# superclasses pyxb.binding.datatypes.anySimpleType
class AnySimple (pyxb.binding.basis.STD_union):

    """container for any simple type"""

    _ExpandedName = pyxb.namespace.ExpandedName(Namespace, 'AnySimple')
    _XSDLocation = pyxb.utils.utility.Location('/home/user/myproject/xsd/Core/PrimitiveTypes.xsd', 36, 3)
    _Documentation = 'container for any simple type'

    _MemberTypes = ( pyxb.binding.datatypes.string, pyxb.binding.datatypes.boolean, pyxb.binding.datatypes.byte, pyxb.binding.datatypes.short, pyxb.binding.datatypes.int, pyxb.binding.datatypes.long, pyxb.binding.datatypes.unsignedByte, pyxb.binding.datatypes.unsignedShort, pyxb.binding.datatypes.unsignedInt, pyxb.binding.datatypes.unsignedLong, pyxb.binding.datatypes.float, pyxb.binding.datatypes.double, pyxb.binding.datatypes.dateTime, pyxb.binding.datatypes.duration, )

AnySimple._CF_pattern = pyxb.binding.facets.CF_pattern()
AnySimple._CF_enumeration = pyxb.binding.facets.CF_enumeration(value_datatype=AnySimple)
AnySimple._InitializeFacetMap(AnySimple._CF_pattern,
        AnySimple._CF_enumeration)
Namespace.addCategoryObject('typeBinding', 'AnySimple', AnySimple)
_module_typeBindings.AnySimple = AnySimple
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be related to this issue, found in the documentation of PyXB: http://pyxb.sourceforge.net/userref_usebind.html#coping-with-wrong-xsi-type-attributes

The error can be solved by adding a line in the code previous to the parsing of the XML file, that relaxes the strictness of the XML interpretation:

```py
pyxb.namespace.builtin.XMLSchema_instance.ProcessTypeAttribute(
    pyxb.namespace.builtin._XMLSchema_instance.PT_lax)
```